# ASP.NET - Javascript timeOut Warning based on sessionState timeOut in web.config

Tags: c#, javascript, session-state, session-timeout

Problem: I am looking to create a time-out warning message on an asp.net page with a c# code behind based off my webconfig sessionState TimeOut Attribute.

Code on web.config:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="EchoSignDocumentService10HttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="1638400" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="EchoSignDocumentService10HttpBinding1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pseudo code:

- Read the timeout setting in codebehind
- Register a ClientScriptblock (`setTimeout` passing the timeout period (20 * 60))
- On timeout, display a warning label on the page

Sample code:

```
    public void RegisterTimeoutWarning(System.Web.UI.Page Page)
    {
        var timeout = HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout * 60 * 1000;
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), 
                "timeoutWarning", 
                string.Format("setTimeout(function () {{ alert('Session about to expire'); }}, {0});", timeout), true);
    }
```

Of course, you can improve the client side display (rather than showing an alert) by displaying warning popups or even a confirm popup which you can then use to renew the session.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this before by creating a web method in my code-behind file that checks for the timeout. Have your Javascript function get the timeout information via AJAX and display a warning according.

**Example**

This is the web method in my code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool HasSessionTimedOut()
{
    HttpSessionState session = HttpContext.Current.Session;

    // I put this value into Session at the beginning.
    DateTime? sessionStart = session[SessionKeys.SessionStart] as DateTime?;

    bool isTimeout = false;

    if (!sessionStart.HasValue)
    {
        isTimeout = true;
    }
    else
    {
        TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - sessionStart.Value;
        isTimeout = elapsed.TotalMinutes > session.Timeout;
    }

    return isTimeout;
}
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                   
    $(function() {                                                 
        var callback = function(isTimeout) {
            if (isTimeout) {                           
                // Show your pop-up here...
            }                         
        };                                                         
        setInterval(                                                
            function() {
                // Don't forget to set EnablePageMethods="true" on your ScriptManager.
                PageMethods.HasSessionTimedOut(false, callback);    
            },                                                     
            30000                                                   
        );                                                          
    });                                                            
</script>
```

So, this is pretty rudimentary. Every 30 seconds, my Javascript function sends an AJAX request to my web method using ASP.NET's PageMethods object. It checks for a return value of true in the callback, which indicates that a timeout has occurred, and takes the appropriate action.

Comment: AJAX isn't something you use versus Javascript. It's a Javascript technique. I'll work on an example.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer, if you care to take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the example & the response!

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to get FishbasketGordo's code to work because the Web Method call kept passing the Boolean value "false" as the onsuccess method. After much research I made the following changes.

```
            $(function () {
                var isTimeout = false;
                var callback = function (isTimeout) {
                    if (isTimeout) {
                        // Show your pop-up here...
                        alert("You have timed out");
                    }
                };

                var failure = function () {
                    alert("Problem with Server");
                };

                setInterval(
                        function () {
                            // Don't forget to set EnablePageMethods="true" on your ScriptManager.
                            PageMethods.HasSessionTimedOut(callback,failure);
                        }, 30000
                );
            });
```

Comment: Actually it appears that the call to the web method is continuing the session. I had the time notification on one page which set a session variable when the page first loaded, and then a button would open a second page in the same session. The second page had a button which checked for the existence of the session variable and would update a label if it existed or redirect to a timeout page if not. Each time the timeout notice reported that the session had timed out, the button reported session variable was still in existence, indicating that the session had in fact not timed out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution (requires a script manager):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //get a hold of the timers
    var iddleTimeoutWarning = null;
    var iddleTimeout = null;

    //this function will automatically be called by ASP.NET AJAX when page is loaded and partial postbacks complete
    function pageLoad() {

        //clear out any old timers from previous postbacks
        if (iddleTimeoutWarning != null)
            clearTimeout(iddleTimeoutWarning);
        if (iddleTimeout != null)
            clearTimeout(iddleTimeout);
        //read time from web.config
        var millisecTimeOutWarning = <%= int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeoutWarning"]) * 60 * 1000 %>;
        var millisecTimeOut = <%= int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeout"]) * 60 * 1000 %>;

        //set a timeout to display warning if user has been inactive
        iddleTimeoutWarning = setTimeout("DisplayIddleWarning()", millisecTimeOutWarning);
        iddleTimeout = setTimeout("TimeoutPage()", millisecTimeOut);
    }

    function DisplayIddleWarning() {
        alert("Your session is about to expire due to inactivity.");
    }

    function TimeoutPage() {
        //refresh page for this sample, we could redirect to another page that has code to clear out session variables
        location.reload();
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a time-out warning message askign the user to save data before the session times out in x number of remaining minutes using the following javascript code on my asp.net edit.aspx page:

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var sessionTimeoutWarning = "<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SessionWarning"].ToString()%>";
    var sessionTimeout = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";

    var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;
    setTimeout('SessionWarning()', sTimeout);

    function SessionWarning() 
    {
        var message = "Your session will expire in another " + (parseInt(sessionTimeout) - parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning)) + " mins! Please Update the data before the session expires";
        alert(message);
    }
</script>
```

I set the frequency of the warning message to every 20 minutes and made it easy to change by putting it as a variable under the application settings, which is also accessible in the web.config under  and defined as a key (SessionWarning) w/ a value to 20 (representing  20 minutes).

Here's the code I used on my web.config file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SessionWarning" value="20" />
        <add key="EchoSignApiKey" value="XZKZ3VT2M*****" />
        <add key="EchoSignSignedDocumentUrl" value="http://echosign:*****.Com/ApplicationFiles/" />
        <!-- dummy -->
        <add key="ImageSaveFolder" value="C:\Development\Temp" />
        <add key="FileSaveFolder" value="C:\Development\Temp" />
        <!-- Test Library-->
        <add key="AS400LIBRARY" value="TPATSTDTA" />
        <add key="AllowVoiceSignature" value="False" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="60" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="EchoSignDocumentService10HttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="1638400" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="EchoSignDocumentService10HttpBinding1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This   [Seesion Alert Using Jquery](http://sumeshparakkat.blogspot.in/2010/11/session-timeout-with-warning-and-jquery.html) from my blog:

- Session set to time out (e.g. 30 minutes).
- When session times out, the user is logged out.
- Display a countdown so the user knows how long is left.
- Inform the user when they are approaching the limit (e.g. 5 minutes left).
- Let the user know that they’ve been automatically timed out due to inactivity.