# ASP.NET session timeout with warning window

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Want to use asp.net membership provider to authenticate and store user information. however, i want to setup a session timeout and show a warning message a few minutes before the session ends.

Was wondering if someone could point me in the direction of how this could be accomplished?

i have successfully implemented membership but not the timeout feature.

thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522482/session-timeout-warning-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You can set a javascript timeout (`settimeout`) to call a function that will bring up a popup with the message. On the popup you could provide a simple submit button if you want to refresh the session. On clicking the submit button a post back would happen and that would refresh your session.

Here is how `settimeout` works http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp.

Hope this helps.