# ASP.NET - Javascript timeout warning and redirect on nested pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session

I'm an ASP.NET newbie, so I apologize in advance for anything that's really obvious or I haven't explained well!

I want my application to, on session timeout, redirect to timedout.aspx, and also display a warning five minutes prior. My current (working) code does something like in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029168/asp-net-javascript-timeout-warning-based-on-sessionstate-timeout-in-web-config). On every page load, in codebehind I grab the current Session.Timeout, and call a utility function that uses page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock to add the following JS code to the page:

```
function SessionTimeoutRedirect(redirectUrl) {
  window.location = redirectUrl;
};
setTimeout('SessionTimeoutRedirect('timeout.aspx'),Session.Timeout * 60000);
```

This JS code is stored in a string and then embedded into a page that is included into every page on the site.

```
If (Not page1.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(StringConstant.SessionExpiredRedirectScriptKey)) Then
  page1.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(System.Web.UI.Page), StringConstant.SessionExpiredRedirectScriptKey, _
    scriptStringBuilder.ToString(), True)
End If
```

I have something similar for the warning.

This would work fine if not for the fact that the application has many different pages rendered within each other: for example, on the first main page, MainPage.aspx, a JS function renders

```
var cp = oDialog.get_contentPane();
cp.set_contentUrl('DialogPage.aspx');
```

So in this case, MainPage.aspx will on page_load add javascript code timing out in 5 minutes, and then once DialogPage.aspx is rendered, Session.Timeout is reset but MainPage.aspx still has the old javascript code with the old timeout. So MainPage.aspx will end up redirecting the window ahead of time.

I have no idea what the solution to this would look like. If Platform.aspx (and DialogPage.aspx might have additional nested pages as well) have to keep polling the server, that's going to reset the session timeout. It doesn't seem possible to reset or remove the RegisterClientScriptBlock javascript code in old pages each time a new page is loaded in the application.

Thanks for your help!